# Delete image from cache

Tags: php, image, apache, caching, nginx

I need when a image is uploaded and replace other one, to delete it from cache.
image is on nginx server (1h expires), and is uploaded through apache & php

Steve Fenton
i can disable cache for that

if i modify the creation date with one hour will update?

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving the image via PHP, you can bust it out of the user's cache by adjusting the URL. For example if you have this:

```
<img src="a.png" alt="Butterfly">
```

The following would ensure the cached `a.png` was not used:

```
<img src="a.png?1" alt="Butterfly">
```

You can use anything - a version number, a timestamp (although it would then never be cached) or anything else that takes your fancy.